# this.props.children is not a function when trying to cluster markers from array using @react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps

I'm trying to take an array of objects with lat/long points and create a `Marker` for each, and then pass those `Marker`s into a `<MarkerClusterer>` component.

By copying straight off the docs [here](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.com/#markerclusterer) I can make it work. However, their approach is a bit different from what I need.

The difference seems to be with how the points are mapped to the component.

Working code:

```
<MarkerClusterer
      options={{imagePath:"https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m"}}
    >
      {
        (clusterer) => [
          {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
          {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
          {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
          {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834}
        ].map((location, i) => (
          <Marker
            key={i}
            position={location}
            clusterer={clusterer}
          />
        ))
      }
    </MarkerClusterer>
```

My non-working code:

```
const listings = [
    { lat: -31.56391, lng: 147.154312 },
    { lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181 },
    { lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124 },
    { lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834 },
  ];
  let testArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < listings.length; i++) {
    let location = listings[i];
    testArray.push(
      <Pin position={location} id={i} key={i} clusterer={listings} />
    );
  }
...

 <MarkerClusterer>
    {testArray}
 </MarkerClusterer>
```

And here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usegooglemap-repro-ljtgp) with an example. Code is under Map2.js and the difference is at line 61.

I can't figure out what the first approach is doing that I'm not. Maybe the clusterer reference? Any help in that area will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<MarkerClusterer>` component requires a function as its child prop. That function will be called by the `<MarkerClusterer>` component's render function. In the second case, you are passing an array as the child prop. Hence the `MarkerClusterer` is trying to invoke your array as a function (`testArray()`) and hence failing.

this should work

```
<MarkerClusterer
  options={{
    imagePath:
      "https://developers.google.com..."
  }}
>
  {clusterer =>
    listings.map((location, i) => (
      <Pin key={i} position={location} clusterer={clusterer} />
    ))
  }
</MarkerClusterer>
```

This is known as render props in the react world. Read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) for more details.

Comment: @colemars did this answer help?